# Prevent column shift after character removal

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

Currently I am using the following oneliner for the removal of special characters:

```
  sed 's/[-$*=+()]//g'
```

However sometimes it occurs that a column only contains the special character `*`.
How can I prevent the column from shifting if it only contains `*`? 
Would it be possible to use a placeholder, so that whenever it occurs that the only character(s) in the columns two and/or four are `*` it gets replaced by `N` for every `*`?

From:

```
6    cc-g*$    10 cc+c
6    c$c$*g$q    10 ***
6    *c*c$$qq    10 ccc
6    **    10 c$cc
6    **    10 *
```

To possibly:

```
6    ccg    10 ccc
6    ccgq    10 NNN
6    ccqq    10 ccc
6    NN    10 ccc
6    NN    10 N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with in awk,

```
awk '{ if($2 ~ /^[*]+$/) { gsub ( /[*]/,"N",$2); } if($4 ~ /^[*]+$/ ){ gsub ( /[*]/,"N",$4); } print  }' your_file.txt  | sed 's/[-$*=+()]//g'
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`. Traverse all fields of each line and substitute special characters unless the field only has `*` characters. After that print them separated with one space.

```
perl -ane '
    for my $pos ( 0 .. $#F ) {
        $F[ $pos ] =~ s/[-\$*=+()]//g unless $F[ $pos ] =~ m/\A\*+\Z/;
    }
    printf qq|%s\n|, join qq| |, @F;
' infile
```

Assuming `infile` has the content of the question, output will be:

```
6 ccg 10 ccc
6 ccgq 10 ***
6 ccqq 10 ccc
6 ** 10 ccc
6 ** 10 *
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/\S*\s*\(\S*\).*/\1/;:a;/^\**$/y/*/N/;s/[*$+=-]//g;H;g;/\n.*\n/bb;s/\(\S*\s*\)\{3\}\(\S*\).*/\2/;ba;:b;s/^\(\S*\s*\)\(\S*\)\([^\n]*\)\n\(\S*\)/\1\4\3/;s/\(\S*\)\n\(.*\)/\2/' file
```